# Veracode still reports OS command injection issue after I have applied the solution as recommendations from OWAPS and Roslyn Security Guard

Tags: injection, .net, secure-coding

Current code in my project is shown below and Veracode reports there is an OS command injection

```
filename = Regex.Replace(filename, "[^a-zA-Z0-9_]", "_") & ".svg"

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = default(ProcessStartInfo);
Process pStart = new Process();
startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(myExecutedFilePath, "\"" + filename + "\" --export-pdf=\"" + filename + "\""); //OS command injection raises at this line
pStart.StartInfo = startInfo;
pStart.Start();
pStart.WaitForExit();
```

So, I research the solution to solve this issue from OWASP and Roslyn Security Guard.

- OWASP post: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OS_Command_Injection_Defense_Cheat_Sheet)
- Roslyn Security Guard post: https://dotnet-security-guard.github.io/SG0001.htm

And here is my code after modifying based on that posts.

```
filename = Regex.Replace(filename, "[^a-zA-Z0-9_]", "_") & ".svg"

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = default(ProcessStartInfo);
Process pStart = new Process();
startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = myExecutedFilePath;
startInfo.Arguments = "\"" + filename + "\" --export-pdf=\"" + filename + "\""; //Veracode still reports the issue at this line
pStart.StartInfo = startInfo;
pStart.Start();
pStart.WaitForExit();
```

BUT, Veracode still reports OS command injection.

So my concerns here are:

1. Did I apply the correct solution to solve OS command injection in this case?
2. Or, Should I propose mitigation for it?

Comment: Please do not cross-post on StackExchange: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51490167/veracode-still-reports-os-command-injection-issue-after-i-have-applied-the-solut  This is better over on SO.